# jQuery Nestable Ajax update

Tags: jquery, ajax

В общем проблема, при обновлении через ajax перестает работать плагин [Nestable](http://dbushell.github.io/Nestable/). Если обновить страницу, все работает.

Обновление стандартно через jquery ajax

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            url: '/menu/update',
            dataType: "html",
            data: {id:id, content:content},
            success: function(data){
                $('#menu').html(data)
                //в data приходит готовый html, вида
                //<div class="dd" id="nestable">ну и здесь все остальное</div>
            }
        });
```

После обновления не работает "перетаскивание"

Comment: В вопросе ещё стоит указать код, связанный с Nestable, и начальный HTML. Пока что могу сказать, что всё выглядит так, что `$('#menu').html(data)` "ломает" всё отображение меню, потому что в `data` у HTML элементов навряд ли присутствуют классы `dd-item`, `dd-list` и другие, на которых держится весь плагин. Можно попытаться проинициализировать меню заново после `$('#menu').html(data)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как плагин навешивает свои классы и обработчики событий (возможно, меняет и HTML структуру), то после замены HTML кода (`$('#menu').html(data)`) имеет смысл проинициализовать меню заново.
Даже если все нужные классы у элементов были установлены в `data`, повторная инициализация требуется для добавления обработчиков событий.